# Spring Boot @Schema different but request models are identical for versioned endpoint

Tags: spring-boot, oop

I have two pojo classes used as request model in my API.  They are identical, the only difference is that one String field named `vin` is 10 char long in one and 11 in another.

They are POJO classes used to model requests, no methods, only fields and getters/setters.

I use these to version my endpoints so v1 can take vin 10 chars long and v2 endpoint can take win number 11 chars long

- POST https://myapi/v1/car
- POST https://myapi/v2/car

```java
    public class carRequest {
      long id;

      @Schema(....)
      @Size(min=10, max=10)
      String vin;

      String type;
      ...
      ... many more fields
    }
```

```java
    public class carRequest2 {
      long id;

      @Schema(....)
      @Size(min=11, max=11)
      String vin;

      String type;
      ...
      ... many more fields
    }
```

Same is with responses, I have `CarResponse` and `CarResponse2` objects which are returned to clients and they are also identical except the `String vin` field which can be either 10 or 11 chars long.

These are request models coming into my controller which then has 2 versioned endpoint paths

```
@RestController
public class CarController {

  @PostMapping(path="/v1/cars")
  public CarResponse saveCar(@Valid @RequestBody CarRequest car) {
     // call service to persist Car with 10 chars vin
  }

  @PostMapping(path="/v2/cars")
  public CarResponse2 saveCar(@Valid @RequestBody CarRequest2 car) {
     // call service to persist Car with 11 chars vin
  }

  ...
}
```

Given that the car requests and responses are identical and the only difference is that `String` field which is validated using `javax.validation` annotation `@Size` to enforce that one must be 10 chars long and another must be 11 chars long, it feels like code smell and lots of duplication.

I have read few articles recommending to do versioning this way (path versioning which is what I want to do), but it just feels like there is lots of code duplication.

I was thinking to create an `abstract class CarRequest` and then extend it in `CarRequest1` and `CarRequest2` which normally makes sense but in this case it does not since the classes are identical, it is only that the `@Schema` validation is different on one field.

What would be a good approach in such scenario?  Or is my approach good?

Comment: In case of minor differences in workflow of the controller method I would introduce a path variable 'version' and implement only one method with a validation coded. The request and response objects only one version without validation annotations.

Comment: @Mar-Z thanks.  I think that is problematic if you remove validation for model with many fields